# C# MailAddress.TryCreate say that email valid even without domain zone

Tags: c#, .net

When I try to validate email e.g.`test@mail` without domain zone e.g. `.com` or `.net` etc.. The method MailAddress.TryCreate say that this email is valid. Why? And how I can add this kind of validation too?

Comment: Don't try to validate emails this way, it's an almost endless rabbit hole, the actual RFCs that make up what a email can and cannot be are huge and even the biggest of email providers accept only a small subset of all valid email addresses. FYI emails without a top level domain are valid emails, more [here](https://serverfault.com/q/721927). What I'd do is define a subset of email addresses to accept, make a regex for it, and only trust an email address once I've sent an email there and the user confirmed they received it. Or skip the validation part entirely and purely rely on a sent link

Comment: Just read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples) on some examples of what email-addresses might be. Many more can be found online. Also ead [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation).